# Почему происходит ошибка с импортом модуля Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Установил виртуальное окружение, установил django, при написании команды

> django-admin —version

показывается нужная версия. Также показывает, что в pip установлено всё что нужно.

```
    (demoEnv) PS E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor> django-admin --version
4.0.4

    (demoEnv) PS E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor> pip list
    Package         Version
    --------------- -------
    asgiref         3.5.0
    dj-database-url 0.5.0
    Django          4.0.4
    gunicorn        20.1.0
    Pillow          9.1.0
    pip             22.0.4
    psycopg2        2.9.3
    setuptools      61.0.0
    sorl-thumbnail  12.8.0
    sqlparse        0.4.2
    tzdata          2022.1
    wheel           0.37.1
    whitenoise      6.0.0
```

При попытке запуска локального сервера выдаёт

```
    (demoEnv) PS E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor> python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv       
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 74, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 81, in handle 
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor\with_tutor\settings.py", line 141, in <module>
    import dj_database_url
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line   
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 427, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\demoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor\with_tutor\settings.py", line 141, in <module>
    import dj_database_url
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url'
```

Затем нашел похожую проблему и скачал все на

> pip install
> И ещё
> pip3 install

Всё должно быть скаченно и работать.
А когда я пишу:

```
(demoEnv) PS E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor> python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor\manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor\manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Выходит совсем другая ошибка. Хотя у меня всё скаченно.

```
(demoEnv) PS E:\frontendprog\slave-projeckt\with_tutor\with_tutor> pip3 list   
Package         Version
--------------- -------
asgiref         3.5.0
dj-database-url 0.5.0
Django          4.0.4
gunicorn        20.1.0
Pillow          9.1.0
pip             22.0.4
psycopg2        2.9.3
setuptools      61.0.0
sorl-thumbnail  12.8.0
sqlparse        0.4.2
tzdata          2022.1
wheel           0.37.1
whitenoise      6.0.0
```

В интернете находил ответ, только то, что надо всё установить на pip3, но у меня всё установлено и на pip и на pip3, и при использовании python и python3 выходят разные ошибки, хотя всё скачено и отзывается. Я уже не представляю что делать.